# I don't have a green card yet. Can I travel to the Schengen countries and return to the US?

Tags: usa, schengen, international-travel

I am in process of getting my Green Card. I am having approved asylee status. Can I travel to Schengen States with this travel document and can I return back to the US safely?

Comment: Can you please confirm exactly what type of travel document you have?

Comment: Entry to other countries also often depends up one's home country citizenship. Thus, this is unanswerable without also knowing the identity of your home country, the one from which you are claiming or have claimed asylum in the US.

Comment: @Daniil I'm not sure about your edit to the second sentence. The OP is not a native English speaker. His version says to me that he has asylee status approved already. Your version says it's in process and not yet approved. The difference is important.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass IMO the OP meant it isn’t yet approved

Comment: @Daniil I gather that. However, in the interests of maintaining accuracy I've reverted that particular change.

Comment: @ALMAS Do you mean that you have you asylee status approved now, or are you waiting for it?

Comment: @Daniil the US asylum process includes a period in which the asylee has been granted asylum but has not yet been granted permanent residency.  That is most likely the situation here.  Another possibility is that the asylee has been granted permanent residency but has not yet received the actual green card.  That is rather less likely, because someone in that situation would in fact have a temporary green card, so would be unlikely to say they "don't have a green card yet."

Answer (score 3):

The [entry ban](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/16/2020-05578/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of) to the US of people who have been to the Schengen Area in the preceding 14 days is still in effect. Until that ban is lifted, if you travel to the Schengen Area, you will not be able to return to the US unless you first go to a country other than the Schengen Area (and other than the [UK or Ireland](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/18/2020-05797/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of), [Mainland China](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/02/05/2020-02424/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-2019), [Iran](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/04/2020-04595/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of), and [Brazil](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/05/28/2020-11616/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of)) for 14 days. The proclamation does not exempt people who hold US Refugee Travel Documents from the entry ban. The only exemptions are if you are certain types of immediate relatives of a US citizen or permanent resident.

In addition, I believe the Schengen Area is currently banning entry of non-EU and non-Schengen-Area nationals, so I don't think you will be able to travel there in the first place.